# How to bundle a mix of shim and non shim vendor libraries with Gulp and Browserify?

Tags: bundle, gulp, browserify, shim

not sure how to get this one working: I have a mix of vendors libraries, some needs to be shimmed and some don't but I would like somehow to bundle them together with browserify while preserving the dependencies.

So I guess my question is how to apply the transform for the libraries that need shim while preserving the dependencies with the one that don't need to be transformed before I bundle all of them? and that in a single task? Thanks